# I can not display BLOB image

Tags: php, html, image

I have a problem , when I try to display image stored in database, it displays only characters and symbols; here is the code I am using:

```
    if ($pass==$dbpass&&$id== $dbid) {

   $queryimage = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `images` FROM `attestation` WHERE id='$id' "))[0];

   echo $queryimage;


    @$_SESSION['id']=$id;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell the browser what kind of data you are sending to it. In HTTP this is done using [headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

This is an example for a png image. For a list of many types see this [link](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html).

Also note that any headers need to be send before any output to the browser. This means any echo and/or any content outside of PHP tags (even white space characters).

So your code would look something like:

```
if ($pass==$dbpass&&$id== $dbid) {
    $queryimage = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `images` FROM `attestation` WHERE id='$id' "))[0];

    header('Content-Type: image/png'); // change this to your actual image type
    echo $queryimage;

    @$_SESSION['id']=$id;
}
```

Comment: Thank you my dear friend..
i have done exactly lik u said..however it displays a small square

Answer (score 0):

This line is being highlighted in Dreamweaver as errornous

```
$queryimage = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `images` FROM `attestation` WHERE id='$id' "))[0];
```

perhaps instead something like this?

```
<?php
    if ( $pass===$dbpass && $id===$dbid ) {

        $sql="SELECT `images` FROM `attestation` WHERE id='$id'";

        $res=mysql_query( $sql );
        $rs=mysql_fetch_array( $res );

        $queryimage=$rs[0];

        $_SESSION['id']=$id;

        header('Content-Type: image/png'); 
        echo $queryimage;
    }
?>
```